# Calling Correct Values of JSON from nested objects

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I am calling in JSON that returns like

Here is an actual part of the JSON file. There is more to it than this but I am just trying to show how I can get nested values.

```js
{
  player: {
    id: 277013255,
    game: "bf4",
    plat: "pc",
    name: "f1ss1on",
    tag: "MCG",
    dateCheck: 1524851054474,
    dateUpdate: 1524849279114,
    dateCreate: 1385342286868,
    dateStreak: 1524849279114,
    lastDay: "20160222",
    country: "",
    countryName: null,
    rank: {
      nr: 33,
      imgLarge: "bf4/ranks/r33.png",
      img: "r33",
      name: "Master Sergeant III",
      needed: 1280000,
      next: {
        nr: 34,
        imgLarge: "bf4/ranks/r34.png",
        img: "r34",
        name: "Master Sergeant IV",
        needed: 1345000,
        curr: 1317090,
        relNeeded: 65000,
        relCurr: 37090,
        relProg: 57.06153846153846
      }
    },
```

My Code is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  "use strict";

  var html = '';
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("https://api.bf4stats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=pc&name=f1ss1on&output=json", function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(i, entry) {
        html += '<ul>';
        html += '<li class="name col-5">' + entry.name + '</li>';
        html += '<li class="date col-3">' + entry.tag + '</li>';
        html += '<li class="assigned col-4">' + entry.rank + '</li>';
        html += '</ul>';
      });
    }
    $('div').html(html);
  });
});
```

The expected return should be

- f1ss1on
- MCG
- 33

But instead I get this in return:

- f1ss1on
- MCG
- [object Object]
- undefined
- undefined
- 33

How can I properly call nested JSON objects onto the correct element?

I have tried doing:

```
entry.rank.nr
```

but this returns "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nr' of undefined"

Comment: your JSON declaration is so weird, I can not understand it, and why you wanna call 28, you wrote `entry.rank`, you should write `entry.rand.level`.

Comment: That's not valid JSON.

Comment: That's both invalid JSON and invalid JavaScript. Please paste the actual content of the network response, or do `JSON.stringify(result)` on the parsed response.

Comment: I wasnt giving full json just trying to show example of how it is nested.

Comment: You might also give a read to the answers to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Fixed all of mentioned concerns for you all. :D

Comment: Okay, so just so you know, it's somewhat odd to use `$.each` on an object. It will run for every top-level property on the returned object. Maybe that's okay, just odd. Also, I would strongly suggest learning to use the debugger and looking at exactly what `entry.rank` is (which is an object, so printing that would actually show `[object Object]` not `undefined` as you've said in your post). Read the proposed duplicate; it has a wealth of information about this.

Comment: Just for clarity, you don't _"call"_ JSON. It is a notation that describes a data structure; you _parse_ JSON to turn the text representation of the data back into an actual data structure.

Comment: Its not cool to down vote just becuase I didnt format perfectly for you all. I appreciate the help but I was trying to put least amount of code in just to show an example of the nesting. 

I fixed everything. SO if you could please relook and help it would be appreciated.

Comment: The only portion of your object that you've shown us is the portion that seems to be working perfectly, so we can't possibly know what's wrong with the next iterations. `rank`, as you can see, has a bunch of properties. You need `entry.rank.nr`. It sounds like the portion of your object that you *haven't shown us* is malformed, and doesn't contain the same properties.

Comment: @TylerRoper I can only put 3000 words into the body so the full JSON can be found at https://api.bf4stats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=pc&name=f1ss1on&output=json

Answer (score 0):

### The Solution

The endpoint you're calling doesn't return multiple players, it returns one single `player` object, so I'm not sure any sort of loop or `each` is necessary.

The following seems to work just fine:

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.bf4stats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=pc&name=f1ss1on&output=json", function(result) {
  var player = result.player;
  console.log("Name:", player.name);
  console.log("Tag:", player.tag);
  console.log("Rank:", player.rank.nr);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

### Explanation Of Your Results

To show exactly what went wrong in your query, open up your browser console and take a look at this. It's your `result` in tabular form.

```js
$.getJSON("https://api.bf4stats.com/api/playerInfo?plat=pc&name=f1ss1on&output=json", function(result) {
  console.table(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

If the table doesn't appear in your console, re-run this snippet with the console already open.
```

Here, you can see the items that you were looping through as rows in the table.

The first item is `player`, which is why `name` and `tag` came back properly, but `rank` came back as an object.

The second item is `stats`. The results in this row explain why your second iteration returned `name` and `tag` as `undefined`, but `rank` as `33`.

I'd imagine you got a whole lot of `undefined`s after that (three for each item).